# As tabelas do html/php nao aparecem

Tags: php, mysql, post, table

Tenho este código, mas o objectivo era quando se clica se em ver, aparecesse a tabela, o problema é que sempre que clico tudo desaparece, e nao cria a tabela.
Se eu retirar a form ele dá, mas tenho que apresentar as 2 tabelas, e eu cria que apresentasse de acordo a escolha do utilizador.

```
<!--Menu ver-->
      <div id="VFunc">
      <form action = "" method = "post">
        <b>Qual pretenda ver:</b><br>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Dep" required> Departamento
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Set" required> Setor
        <input type="submit" name="BtnP" value="Ver">
      </form>
      <?php 
      if (isset($_POST["BtnP"])){
        if ($_POST["gender"]=="Dep"){
          echo "<table>";
          echo"<tr>";
          echo"<th>Id Departamento</th>";
          echo"<th>Nome Departamento</th>";
          echo"</tr>";
          $sql="SELECT * FROM departamentos";
          $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
              while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>$row[IdDepartamento]</td>";
                echo "<td>$row[NomeDepartamento]</td>";
                echo"</tr>";
                echo"</table>";
              }
          }else{
            echo "0 resultados";
          }
        }elseif ($_POST["gender"]=="Set"){ 
          echo "<table>";
          echo"<tr>";
          echo"<th>Id Setor</th>";
          echo"<th>Nome Setor</th>";
          echo"</tr>";
          $sql="SELECT * FROM setores"; 
          $result = $conn->query($sql);
          if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$row[IdSetor]</td>";
            echo "<td>$row[Nome]</td>";
            echo"</tr>";
            echo"</table>";
          }
            } else {
              echo "0 resultados";
          } 
        }
      }
          $conn->close();
            ?>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No seu código é possível notar que você está criando as tabelas dinamicamente de forma incorreta.

Caso a condição seja verdadeira para `$_POST["gender"]=="Dep"` ou para o `$_POST["gender"]=="Set"` o seu código terá o seguinte comportamento.

A tag `<table>` será criada quando a condição do **if** for verdadeira e somente será fechada (`</table>`) quando existir registros na tabela. Caso não exista registros na tabela, a tag não será fechada e executará o `echo "0 resultados";`. Mas também, se existir registros, o fechamento está dentro do loop `while`, ou seja, para cada registro será fechada a tabela (`</table>`).

Solução:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["BtnP"])) {
    if ($_POST["gender"] == "Dep") {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM departamentos";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>Id Departamento</th>";
            echo "<th>Nome Departamento</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>$row[IdDepartamento]</td>";
                echo "<td>$row[NomeDepartamento]</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
        } else {
            echo "0 resultados";
        }
    }

    if ($_POST["gender"] == "Set") {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM setores";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>Id Setor</th>";
            echo "<th>Nome Setor</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>$row[IdSetor]</td>";
                echo "<td>$row[Nome]</td>";
                echo "</tr>";

            }
            echo "</table>";
        } else {
            echo "0 resultados";
        }
    }
}
$conn->close();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="VFunc">
          <form action = "" method = "post">
            <b>Qual pretenda ver:</b><br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Dep" required> Departamento
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Set" required> Setor
            <input type="submit" name="BtnP" value="Ver">
          </form>
          <?php 
          if (isset($_POST["BtnP"])){
            if ($_POST["gender"]=="Dep"){
              echo "<table>";
              echo"<tr>";
              echo"<th>Id Departamento</th>";
              echo"<th>Nome Departamento</th>";
              echo"</tr>";
              $sql="SELECT * FROM departamentos";
              $result = $conn->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>$row[IdDepartamento]</td>";
                    echo "<td>$row[NomeDepartamento]</td>";
                    echo"</tr>";
                    echo"</table>";
                  }
              }else{
                echo "0 resultados";
              }
            }elseif ($_POST["gender"]=="Set"){ 
              echo "<table>";
              echo"<tr>";
              echo"<th>Id Setor</th>";
              echo"<th>Nome Setor</th>";
              echo"</tr>";
              $sql="SELECT * FROM setores"; 
              $result = $conn->query($sql);
              if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
              while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>$row[IdSetor]</td>";
                echo "<td>$row[Nome]</td>";
                echo"</tr>";
                echo"</table>";
              }
                } else {
                  echo "0 resultados";
              } 
            }
          }
              $conn->close();
                ?>
          </div>
```